# How to center navbar links in Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, navbar

I have a navbar and I would like to center the links inside. I've tried adding mx-auto and text-center. Nothing is working. My code below?

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark text-center">
  <div class="container text-center">
    <a class="navbar-brand text-center" href="#"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Hi, not entirely sure what you mean. I put your code into a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/209291/) and it seems to be centered within the containers. Check the bootstrap version?

Comment: available in http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/examples/navbars/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Place the mx-auto in the ul and it will center the links

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark text-center">
  ...
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mx-auto">
        ...
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NLyOwg) with your example